# Template Template argument not in scope

Tags: c++, templates, scope

Within this snippet of code...

```
template<template <unsigned int R,class T,class...Args> class F,typename...G>
class testclass{
protected:
    F<R,T,Args...> f;
};
```

g++ insists `R`,`T` and `Args...` are not declared in the scope of member variable `f`.
What is the proper syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: Uh, what are you trying to do? `R`, `T`, and `Args...` aren't given when `testclass` is instantiated.

Comment: `testclass` is template class with one template parameter `F`. I am trying to define a member variable `f` of same _instantiated_ type as that `F`.

Comment: `F` is not a type, it's a template. It doesn't represent a concrete type at instantiation of `testclass`; the parameters just tell you what `F` *expects*.

Comment: I have Stroustrup's 4th ed. but didn't see mention anywhere that template template parameter are inaccessible. Any good internet links on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only allowed to name the arguments of a template-template parameter as a formality, you can't actually use them anywhere. However, you can access the arguments by specializing your class:

```c++
template <class F, typename... G>
class testclass;

template <template <unsigned int, class...> class F, unsigned int R, class T,
          class... Args, class... G>
class testclass<F<R, T, Args...>, G...>
{
protected:
    F<R, T, Args...> f;
};
```

`T` can actually be replaced with `Args...` unless you need it specifically.